# How to attach application with Facebook publisher?

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-wall, publisher

Many time I found several facebook application on my attach list of publisher.
How can I do it  for my Facebook application?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using facebook-connect and want to publish feed stories, then you need to use the Feed Forms here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Feed_Forms

Comment: Actually I want to attach my app with facebook pulisher [publisher is that input box where you write your status , as you attach youtube videos & music , i want to add my app there]

Comment: I found my answer actually I need to do set it into advance tab of application -setting , set it according to this http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Publisher